# Has there been any research conducted to understand the motivation behind discrete murders in France?

Tags: islam, western-world

there had been numerous cases of knife attacks and stabbing sprees in France. A few days ago, there had been an attack in Paris.

Has there been any research conducted to understand the motivation behind discrete murders?

For example, has someone ever conducted any psychological, sociological, or anthropological study to understand what the murderers were thinking and what life experience motivate such kind of thinking?

Comment: isn't the lesson about cartoons the motive? Stupid is as stupid does.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there have.

Here's [one, sorry, in French](https://www.ifri.org/sites/default/files/atoms/files/hecker_137_nuances_de_terrorisme_2018.pdf).

Basically, at least in France, they are losers, in the *literal* sense of the word.  Poor, poorly educated, young and often recruited while in prison for minor non-terrorist crimes.

Here's the abstract:

> This  study,  based  on  original  judicial  sources,  assesses  the  profiles  of  137 individuals sentenced in France for cases related to jihadism. Among other things,  the  study  reveals  several  common  denominators  including  a lower level of education, poorer integration into the labor market, higher levels of criminal  activity,  and  stronger  ties  to  the  Maghreb  and  to  sub-Saharan Africa  than  the  average  French citizen. Moreover,  a  qualitative  analysis provides    an understanding    of   the   processes    of    radicalization    and subsequent  participation  in  terrorist  activities.  As  such,  it  expounds  the role played  by  group  dynamics,  the  internet,  and  prisons. This  study further illustrates the strains imposed on the judicial and penal systems by the jihadist phenomenon. Relapse is specifically explored, notably through the  cases  of  individuals  convicted of terrorism,  who,  after  serving  their sentence,  launched  attacks  on  French  soil.  The  subject  is  all  the  more topical  in  light  of  the  likely  release from  prison of  some  sixty  individuals, sentenced for acts of terrorism, in the upcoming two years.

Anecdotally, it seems that often when you read about them, they were not achieving much, possibly were into alcohol and substance abuse and were not even necessarily very religious to start with.  The recruiters gave them a sense of belonging to something greater.

Is Islam to blame?  Well, certainly the particular perversion of Islam that these people got exposed to is to blame.  But I wouldn't be surprised if one of the better ways to avoid radicalization is proper religious upbringing with normal, non-radical, Muslim teachings to inoculate against contamination by what are essentially sects.  People who are knowledgeable about their own religion tend to be less susceptible to doomsday peddling charlatans.

The tendency of Western society to conflate Islam in general with Islamic extremism is probably a significant factor in encouraging an "us vs them" mentality.  Books like [Houellebecq 's Submission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submission_(novel)), a turgid rant against Muslims, would be rightfully crucified if it covered any other faith rather than Muslims.  [Hirsi Ali's Nomad 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomad:_From_Islam_to_America) at some point claims it would be a good idea for governments to support Muslim to Christian conversions.  With all due respect to her interesting book and horrible life experiences, this is a terrible idea.  Islam does need to reform itself away from its (too numerious) loonies however.  Just like Christianity is not generally associated with splinter hate-mongers like [Westboro](https://www.splcenter.org/fighting-hate/extremist-files/group/westboro-baptist-church).

Note however that I cast my net pretty wide when it comes to "extremism".  For example, any religious funding by say Saudi Arabia, whose religious orthodoxy is [Wahhabism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahhabism#Criticism_and_controversy) should be thoroughly scrutinized and rejected generally.  France long had an arm's length relationship with Muslim community funding and let Saudi Arabia finance many mosques.

Comment: Please change "they are losers" to something else. Anything else. That they are economically depressed, there is no doubt. Using "losers" has a terrible negative connotation that implies that it is their fault. The causes are deep, some their own fault, some society's.

Comment: @DavidHammen  You know what?  First, considering that we are discussing folk who cut off people's heads, I'll stick to my terminology and you are welcome to write your own answer.  Second, the fact that they are losers and see themselves perceived as such by society is precisely part of the problem.  Calling them "economically disadvantaged" is a nice euphemism, but doesn't give much insight into their reactions.  Most "economically depressed" people don't do this stuff.

Comment: @DavidHammen - It's always one's own fault when someone decides to murder someone. There may well be other *causes*, which is good to know at the level of policy, but the moral responsibility of such a murder is that of the perpetrator. Yes, "loser" has a terrible negative connotation. So does "murderer".